# Rmmod module reappeared after plugging back device

Tags: kernel-modules, drivers

I have an arduino that talks to my computer through the serial-usb driver ftdi. I want to use my own module instead when I plug my arduino.

I did :

- `sudo rmmod usbserial`
- `sudo rmmod ftdi_sio`
- I wrote a driver that does nothing but logs "init/probe/exit"
- `lsmod` shows my driver and doesnt show usbserial/ftdi_sio
- `sudo depmod -a`
- I plug my arduino
- `lsmod` shows usbserial/ftdi_sio

And instead of seeing my logs in dmesg I see that usbserial and ftdi_sio were instanciated.

What should I do do override that ?

P.S code :

```
static struct usb_device_id id_table [] = { 
  { USB_DEVICE(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID) },
  { },
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE (usb, id_table);
...
static struct usb_driver arduino_driver = { 
  .name =   "thomasftdi",
  .probe =  arduino_probe,
  .disconnect = arduino_disconnect,
  .id_table = id_table,
};
init...probe...
```

I didn't use modalias in the code nor in commands, should I add it somewhere to register the module ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the file /lib/modules//modules.alias (and neighbors), and perhaps any relevant udev(8) rules that load the module you don't want. Be extremely careful here, a typo might make your system unbootable.

Comment: I have deleted manually the lines corresponding to ftdi_sio and added mine instead. And it didn't work...